# Add file name as a new column with awk

Tags: awk, filenames, basename

First of all existing questions didn't solve my problem that's why I am asking again.

I have two txt files temp.txt

```
adam    12
george  15
thomas  20
```

and demo.txt

```
mark    8
richard 11
james   18
```

I want to combine them and add a 3rd column as their file names without extension, like this:

```
adam    12   temp
george  15   temp
thomas  20   temp
mark    8    demo
richard 11   demo
james   18   demo
```

I used this script:

```
for i in $(ls); do name=$(basename -s .txt $i)| awk '{OFS="\t";print $0, $name} ' $i; done
```

But it yields following table:

```
mark    8   mark    8
richard 11  richard 11
james   18  james   18
adam    12  adam    12
george  15  george  15
thomas  20  thomas  20
```

I don't understand why it gives the name variable as the whole table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: have a look at the awk variable `FILENAME`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, you need to unmask `$name` which is inside the single quotes, so does not get replaced by the filename from the shell. After you do that, you need to add double quotes around `$name` so that awk sees that as a string:

```
for i in $(ls); do name=$(basename -s .txt $i); awk '{OFS="\t";print $0, "'$name'"} ' $i; done
```

Comment: This will fail in peculiar ways if the file names contain quotes, semicolons, whitespace, etc.

Comment: This contains multiple anti-patterns and additional inefficiencies.

Answer (score 3):

Awk has no access to Bash's variables, or vice versa. Inside the Awk script, `name` is undefined, so `$name` gets interpreted as `$0`.

Also, [don't use `ls` in scripts,](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Finally, the assignment of `name` does not print anything, so piping its output to Awk makes no sense.

```
for i in ./*; do
    name=$(basename -s .txt "$i")
    awk -v name="$name" '{OFS="\t";print $0, $name}' "$i"
done
```

As such, the `basename` calculation could easily be performed natively in Awk, but I leave that as an exercise. (Hint: `sub(regex, "", FILENAME)`)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` has a `FILENAME` variable whose value is the path of the file being processed, and a `FNR` variable whose value is the current line number in the file;
so, at `FNR == 1` you can process `FILENAME` and store the result in a variable that you'll use afterwards:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 {
        basename = FILENAME
        sub(".*/", "", basename)      # strip from the start up to the last "/"
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/, "", basename) # strip from the last "." up to the end
    }
    { print $0, basename }
' ./path/temp.txt ./path/demo.txt
```

```
adam    12   temp
george  15   temp
thomas  20   temp
mark    8    demo
richard 11   demo
james   18   demo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH:

```
for i in temp.txt demo.txt ; do  while read -r a b ; do printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$a" "$b" "${i%%.*}" ; done <"$i" ; done
```

Output:

```
adam    12  temp
george  15  temp
thomas  20  temp
mark    8   demo
richard 11  demo
james   18  demo
```

For each source file read each line and use `printf` to output tab-delimited columns including the current source file name without extension via bash parameter expansion.